# Create a Web application - What is the best and easiest way for a newbie in web programming?

Tags: html, asp.net, web-applications

I have experience developing Desktop application (not Web application) using Visual Studio 2005 to 2010 and C#/VB.NET (Preferably C#). Now, I have to build a web application, this would be my first web application. This web application should be published in a Windows 2008 server machine which uses IIS as a webserver and it has a basic UI where user should select the tests to be passed which are:

- Pings localy and remotely to other machines
- Check if a port is opened in another machine (sockets)
- Check if a Windows service is started and running (status) on another machine.
- Check if an SQL instance is running and available on another machine
- The web application must support multilanguage
- The web application must support authentication, I mean, a login form where user enters username and password.

As I am completely new in programming web applications, I have thought in using ASP.NET and C# under VS 2010 (NET Framework 4.0) because Visual Studio IDE is much easier to understand and rapidly program something and there a lot of things automated like login control, multilanguage is relatively easy to implement using resources files, there are specific objects already created to do pings (Ping object), to check a port using sockets (Sockect Object), to check if windows service is running (ServiceController object), etc...
I think using other tools and programming languages like PHP or javascript will be more complicated to do those things for a person totaly new in programming web applications. So I think the best choice for me is ASP.NET. Also as far as I know those things are imposible to do using only plain HTML code, right?

By taking into account that I have no experience in programing web applications (only desktop ones), my requirements and the technologies I have used, which is the best technology to use?

Comment: You have enough rep to know that questions like these are off-topic at Stack Overflow.

Comment: I do not agree at all this question is off-topic as in my case the answers are or should be answered according to my experience and requirements and not interpreted as opinions.Maybe the correct question should be: What is the best approach according my experience and requirements?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Wrong.

You can use plain HTML and use HTTP-Post form submit and CGI.
But I wouldn't recommend it.

When you already have Windows Server + SQL server given, go with ASP.NET.

If for some odd reason, you find ASP.NET too unchallenging, you can read this:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9433/Understanding-CGI-with-C
and go with plain HTML and CGI.

If you find ASP.NET too boring and old, you can try something new with ASP.NET MVC3/4 :)

Answer (score -1):

[Ruby on Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/) is immensely popular and definitely worth a look.

Plus it would give you an opportunity to learn a language that is much different from what you already know.

Comment: I agree with you. Sure Ruby on Rails would be great and a good oportunity to learn something new but taking into account that I have no much time and I need to implement something quickly and I am very familiar with C# and Visual Studio IDE, just right now I see more suitable to use ASP.NET. I will take it into account for the next time.